# What does the "-" in front of the arccos do to its result, when wanting to compute the polar coordinates of a complex number?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

so I'm still training for my calculus exam but I stumbled upon a confusing thing again :( I think I kind of feel certain with computing polar coordinates now, but I just don't know if my train of thought with this one is right.

Soooo I have these three exercises, where I'm trying to come up with the respective $\arccos$ part that needs to be computed for $\varphi$ in $z=re^{i\varphi}$:

$$(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i) \Rightarrow r=1 \Rightarrow -\arccos{(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})} = -(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = \frac{7\pi}{6}.$$

my understanding of the whole thing is that, for every negative minus sign, we move one quadrant to the left in the polar grid, to the corresponding value of $\cos$. I'm really really bad at explaining so I'll just draw what I mean:

[the blue arrow is for the minus in front of the argument within $\arccos$, the red arrow for the $-$ in front of $\arccos$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUHFg.jpg)

and for another exercise, it's pretty much the same:

$$(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i) \Rightarrow r=1 \Rightarrow -\arccos{(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})} = -(\frac{3\pi}{4}) = \frac{5\pi}{4}.$$

[with the same argumentation as above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ni2q.jpg)

HOWEVER,, now, when I try to use this trick for the following exercise

$$(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i) \Rightarrow r=1 \Rightarrow -\arccos{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})} = -(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{11\pi}{6}.$$

that is the sample solution. BUT, according to what I've gotten accustomed to, the arrow should only be moving from $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to $\frac{5\pi}{6}$, not to $\frac{11\pi}{6}$.

[like demonstrated here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnjVS.jpg)

could someone please explain to me in simple terms what in particular is wrong with my way of thinking?... I would appreciate it so much ;-;

thank you guys in advance <3

Comment: It is $-\arccos$ because its sine is also negative, and that, as by definition, the codomain of $\arccos$ being $[0,\pi]$, the sine on such an interval is nonnegative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not using
\begin{align*}
|-\sqrt{3}/2 - \mathrm{i}/2| &= 1  \text{,}  \\
\Re(-\sqrt{3}/2 - \mathrm{i}/2) &= -\sqrt{3}/2  \text{, and }  \\
\Im(-\sqrt{3}/2 - \mathrm{i}/2) &= -1/2  \text{, so}  \\
\theta &= 7\pi/6  \text{.}
\end{align*}

The first guarantees that we have extracted $r$, so have a point on the unit circle.  If hte magnitude is not $1$ extract $r$, then proceed.  The second and third pull out the coordinates of the point on that circle, $(x,y) = (-\sqrt{3}/2, -1/2)$ using the real part ($\Re$) and imaginary part ($\Im$) functions.  The last is the angle in your unit circle diagram for the point that has those coordinates.

Comment: ahhhhh!! so you're saying I just have to consider both the corresponding $\arccos$ values of the real and imaginary part of the number, and choose just that part of the unit circle where these values are consonant, i.e., leading to the same pi value??

Comment: @LinShao : Possibly.  A "safe way" to proceed is to ignore the signs of the real and imaginary parts, find the *reference angle* (which is always $0$ or in quadrant I), then add multiples of $\pi/2$ to get it back into its original quadrant (or back to its original axis, if it is a quadrantal angle).

Comment: hmmm so if I understood this right, I'm just gonna have to [link](https://imgur.com/a/9JJkztw) memorize this table and the $sgn(cos,sin)$ of the unit circle if you can call it that, ranging from $(+,+)$ to $(-,+)$ to $(-,-)$ to $(+,-)$ (from right to left) to decide which quadrant (the "original quadrant") I have to go to?

Comment: @LinShao : I suppose.  But there should be nothing *new* to memorize.  You know cosine gives $x$-coordinates on the unit circle and you know the left half-plane has $x < 0$ and the  right half-plane has $x > 0$.  Similarly, you know sine gives the $y$-coordinates, the upper half-plane has $y > 0$ and the lower half-plane gives $y < 0$.

Comment: thanks eric :))